# Free resources for learning R

Tags: r, references

I'm interested in learning [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) on the cheap. What's the best free resource/book/tutorial for learning R?

Comment: You should add your background. Programmers who came to R have different issues than people without a programming background.

Comment: Refer to SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192369/books-for-learning-the-r-language/2270793

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375808/learning-r-where-does-one-start on SO

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Some useful R links (find out the link that suits you):

**Intro:**

- for R basics http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/usingR.pdf
- for data manipulation http://had.co.nz/plyr/plyr-intro-090510.pdf
- http://portal.stats.ox.ac.uk/userdata/ruth/APTS2012/APTS.html
- Interactive intro to R programming language https://www.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-r
- Application focused R tutorial https://www.teamleada.com/tutorials/introduction-to-statistical-programming-in-r
- In-browser learning for R http://tryr.codeschool.com/

*with a focus on economics:*

- lecture notes with R code [http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~econ472/e-Tutorial.html](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/%7Eecon472/e-Tutorial.html)
- A brief guide to R and Economics [http://people.su.se/~ma/R_intro/R_intro.pdf](http://people.su.se/%7Ema/R_intro/R_intro.pdf)

**Graphics: plots, maps, etc.:**

- tutorial with info on plots http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Rossiter-RIntro-ITC.pdf
- a graph gallery of R plots and charts with supporting code http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/
- A tutorial for Lattice [http://osiris.sunderland.ac.uk/~cs0her/Statistics/UsingLatticeGraphicsInR.htm](http://osiris.sunderland.ac.uk/%7Ecs0her/Statistics/UsingLatticeGraphicsInR.htm)
- Ggplot R graphics http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/
- Ggplot Vs Lattice @ http://had.co.nz/ggplot/vs-lattice.html
- Multiple tutorials for using ggplot2 and Lattice http://learnr.wordpress.com/tag/ggplot2/
- Google Charts with R http://www.iq.harvard.edu/blog/sss/archives/2008/04/google_charts_f_1.shtml
- Introduction to using RGoogleMaps @ http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RgoogleMaps/vignettes/RgoogleMaps-intro.pdf
- Thematic Maps with R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260965/developing-geographic-thematic-maps-with-r
- geographic maps in R http://smartdatacollective.com/Home/22052

**GUIs:**

- Poor Man GUI for R http://wiener.math.csi.cuny.edu/pmg/
- R Commander is a robust GUI for R http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html
- JGR is a Java-based GUI for R http://jgr.markushelbig.org/Screenshots.html

**Time series & finance:**

- a good beginner’s tutorial for Time Series http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/index.html
- Interesting time series packages in R http://robjhyndman.com/software
- advanced time series in R http://www.wise.xmu.edu.cn/2007summerworkshop/download/Advanced%20Topics%20in%20Time%20Series%20Econometrics%20Using%20R1_ZongwuCAI.pdf
- provides a great analysis and visualization framework for quantitative trading http://www.quantmod.com/
- Guide to Credit Scoring using R http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Sharma-CreditScoring.pdf
- an Open Source framework for Financial Analysis http://www.rmetrics.org/

**Data / text mining:**

- A Data Mining tool in R http://rattle.togaware.com/
- An online e-book for Data Mining with R [http://www.liaad.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/](http://www.liaad.up.pt/%7Eltorgo/DataMiningWithR/)
- Introduction to the Text Mining package in R http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf

**Other statistical techniques:**

- Quick-R http://www.statmethods.net/
- annotated guides for a variety of models http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/default.htm
- Social Network Analysis http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2008/slides/Bojanowski.pdf

**Editors:**

- Komodo Edit R editor http://www.sciviews.org/SciViews-K/index.html
- Tinn-R makes for a good R editor http://www.sciviews.org/Tinn-R/
- An Eclipse plugin for R @ http://www.walware.de/goto/statet
- Instructions to install StatET in Eclipse http://www.splusbook.com/Rintro/R_Eclipse_StatET.pdf
- RStudio http://rstudio.org/
- Emacs Speaks Statistics, a statistical language package for Emacs http://ess.r-project.org/

**Interfacing w/ other languages / software:**

- to embed R data frames in Excel via multiple approaches http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/export-data-frames-to-multi-worksheet-excel-file/
- provides a tool to make R usable from Excel http://www.statconn.com/
- Connect to MySQL from R http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/8/20/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-r-in-wndows-using-rmysql
- info about pulling data from SAS, STATA, SPSS, etc. http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html
- Latex [http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eleisch/Sweave/)
- R2HTML http://www.feferraz.net/en/P/R2HTML

**Blogs, newsletters, etc.:**

- A very informative blog http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/
- A blog aggregator for posts about R  http://www.r-bloggers.com/
- R mailing lists  http://www.r-project.org/mail.html
- R newsletter (old)  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/
- R journal (current)  http://journal.r-project.org/

**Other / uncategorized:** (as of yet)

- Web Scraping in R http://www.programmingr.com/content/webscraping-using-readlines-and-rcurl
- a very interesting list of packages that is seriously worth a look http://www.omegahat.org/
- Commercial versions of R @ http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/
- Red R for R tasks http://code.google.com/p/r-orange/
- KNIME for R (worth a serious look) http://www.knime.org/introduction/screenshots
- R Tutorial for Titanic https://statsguys.wordpress.com/

Comment: This list was becoming less usable. It needs to be organized & at least somewhat standardized to be useful. However, there is no reason to think my reworked version is ideal; eg I'm not familiar w/ all the links. People w/ more expertise should feel free to add / change / shuffle or otherwise reorganize.

Answer (score 24):

If I had to choose one thing, make sure that you read ["The R Inferno"](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

There are many good resources on [the R homepage](http://www.r-project.org), but in particular, read ["An Introduction to R"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) and ["The R Language Definition"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf).

Comment: Agreed, though I'd choose it as my second book, after _R Cookbook (O'Reilly)_ (not free!)  _R Inferno_ felt like _Cookbook Part 2_.

Comment: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/hints_R_begin.html is sort of Circle 0 of 'The R Inferno'.  I agree with Darren -- I don't see the Inferno as introductory.

Answer (score 18):

[Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/index.html) can be a good place to start.

A little bit data mining oriented [R and Data Mining](http://www.rdatamining.com) resources: [Examples and Case Studies](http://www.rdatamining.com/docs/r-and-data-mining-examples-and-case-studies) and [R Reference Card for Data Mining](http://www.rdatamining.com/docs/R-refcard-data-mining.pdf).

Answer (score 13):

- If you like learning through videos, I collated a [list of R training videos](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/05/videos-on-data-analysis-with-r.html).
- I also prepared a [general post on learning R](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/06/learning-r-for-researchers-in.html) with  suggestions on books, online manuals, blogs, videos, user interfaces, and more.

Answer (score 11):

Try IPSUR, Introduction to Probability and Statistics Using R. It's a free book, free in the GNU sense of the word.

http://ipsur.r-forge.r-project.org/book/index.php

It's definitely open source - on the download page you can download the LaTeX source or the lyx source used to generate this.

Comment: That URL didn't work for me, but this did:   http://ipsur.r-forge.r-project.org/book/index.html

Answer (score 8):

The official guides are pretty nice; check out http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html . There is also a lot of contributed documentation there.

Answer (score 8):

If you're an economist/econometrician then Grant Farnworth's paper on using R is indispensable and is available on CRAN at:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Farnsworth-EconometricsInR.pdf

Answer (score 8):

If you have experience in other languages, these "R Rosetta Stone" videos may be useful:

1. [Python](http://www.vcasmo.com/video/drewconway/7183)
2. [MATLAB](http://www.vcasmo.com/video/drewconway/7211)
3. [SQL](http://www.vcasmo.com/video/drewconway/7210)

These are all included in the [video list added by Jeromy](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/05/videos-on-data-analysis-with-r.html), so big +1 for his list.

Answer (score 8):

One resource is 'Some hints for the R beginner' at
http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/hints_R_begin.html

Comment: Welcome -- Nice to see you here, Pat!

Answer (score 7):

I have written a document that is freely available at my website and on CRAN. See the linked page:

[icebreakeR](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~andrewpr/r-users/)

The datasets that are used in the document are also linked from that page.  Feedback is welcome and appreciated!

Andrew

Answer (score 6):

After you learn the basics, I find the following sites very useful:

1. [R-bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/).
2. Subscribing to the [Stack overflow R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/R).

Answer (score 6):

A large number of short videos that cover a **lot** of useful tasks with `R` (91 videos as of March 2013): http://www.twotorials.com/

Here's a nice new interactive online tutorial on the basics of `R`: http://tryr.codeschool.com/

Answer (score 5):

The [R project](http://www.r-project.org/) website has lots of manuals to start, and I suggest you the [Nabble R forum](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/) and the [R-bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/) site as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you already know another programming language, [these notes](http://www.johndcook.com/R_language_for_programmers.html) may help point out some of the ways R might surprise you.

Answer (score 4):

I liked these lectures: [Statistical Aspects of Data Mining](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=statistical+aspects+of+data+mining&aq=0). The lecturer is solving example problems using R.

Answer (score 4):

If you are coming from a SAS or SPSS background, check out:

http://sites.google.com/site/r4statistics/

This is the companion site to the book, R for SAS and SPSS Users by Robert Muenchen and a free version of the book can be found here.

Answer (score 4):

One more:  R bloggers has many posts with tutorials materials:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/?s=tutorial

Answer (score 2):

There are some very good learning materials here: http://scc.stat.ucla.edu/mini-courses/materials-from-past-mini-courses/spring-2009-mini-course-materials/

Answer (score 2):

Look for R Users Groups in your area.  They are growing around the world.

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/local-r-groups.html

If you don't have one then help get one started.  I'm sure you will be able to find like minded interested folks.

As for helpful links the Dallas R Users Group has a nice list.

http://www.meetup.com/Dallas-R-Users-Group/pages/R_Helpful_Links/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.datamind.org offers interactive R tutorials, currently focused at real beginners

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a beginners tutorial to R in the context of Econometrics this may be a good starting point as well: http://www.quandl.com/learn/working-with-quandl-and-r