# Creating plots for String type columns in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have imported a datafile in R. It has different columns. There is one column that has the name of Operating System belonging to that row information. I wanted to get the **percentage** share of each unique OS (windows, linux, ios etc) from this column and plot it. I am very new to R and would like to know if there is any inbuilt way to do this in R.

Comment: Since you're new to R, I recommend checking out this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r) to find a good list of resources to help get you up and running doing some analysis.

Comment: @Chase thanks for the link, yah i need to really learn the language, this was just something I need to do quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `barplot()` will be your friend in that case, e.g.

```
x <- sample(c("Win","Linux","Mac"), 100, replace=TRUE)
barplot(table(x))
```

This will work for variables of type `character` or `factor`. Another option is to use Cleveland's [dotplot](http://www.b-eye-network.com/view/2468), see `dotchart()` (or `dotplot()`in the [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) package).

**Update**

You could replace `table(x)` by `table(x)/sum(table(x))*100` to express data as % rather than counts. I know there are more elegant solutions in additional packages, but I can't remember their names actually. The `table()` function will also work for two-way classification, and marginal totals can easily be computed in a similar way; e.g. `apply(table(x, y), 1, sum)` gives rows marginal frequencies.

Comment: hmm the table function is a useful one it seems, but it would be better if I could show the percentages of the share rather than the count of each OS. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @sfactor I've updated my response accordingly.

Comment: You guys are after the function `prop.table()` which comes with base R, it's essentially a wrapper for what you've got above. With your example, you'd want something like `prop.table(table(x))`

Comment: @Chase (+1) Huh, yes... That's it! I was thinking of even more complex ways with `addmargins()` or `margin.table()`.

Answer (score 4):

Simulating some data for a good start

```
x<-sample(c("Win","Linux","Mac"),721,replace=TRUE)
```

The good practice is to hold such categorical variables as factors; one can convert character vector to factor with `factor` function:

```
x<-factor(x)
```

Then, `plot` called on it will make a barplot with counts; to convert it into per-cents, you can use `table` that makes counts of each level:

```
t<-table(x); barplot(t/sum(t)*100,ylab="Per cent")
```