# Where to find a good beginner's R Primer?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for learning R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r)

I would like to learn more about statistics.   I don't feel like doing multivariable regression by hand.  So I downloaded R because its free; however, I haven't found a good introduction upon how to use it. I do want to RTFM, but I want a good manual to read.

I would like example that I could follow:

T-test: follow this script. 
Linear Regression: Follow this script.

Something along those lines.

Sorry, if this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Have checked the [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r

Comment: @mnel thanks, I tried searching with the box on the top for R, but just got a bunch of specific question about R, nothing general.

Comment: @Jase, thanks alot- that is exactly what I need.

Comment: Did you follow the links within the tag wiki? [This link](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/index.html) would appear to be an obvious candidate

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html

Comment: @MaoYiyi, don't be discouraged by downvotes (and if you don't like the question, vote to close it if you have the rep, or bring it up with the review mechanism to the moderators' attention). This is a good question on its own, but obviously there's a backlog of similar questions on the site. As we strive to generate one answer to these closely related questions, closing yours with a good link to these existing resources is the main course of action.

Comment: @StaK for me I find it very hard to search for questions. I type sentences or ideas into the search box and do not find what I am looking for then post a question and then get told its already been asked. I am not mad. Just wish I had the smart to improve the search. Plus, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 4):

I like Peter Dalgaard's *Introductory Statistics with R*. I think it would be good for you because it talks about the actual statistics that are being covered, along with explaining the intricacies of the R world.

Comment: Sounds good, but it cost money, thus out of my price range.

Comment: I also like IceBreaker (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Robinson-icebreaker.pdf)! I've used that and the Dalgaard book in courses teaching R to non-statistics folk. When you get the opportunity, you should consider purchasing the Dalgaard text though, it's a great reference to have around!

Comment: @I'll ask Santa Klaus

Answer (score 3):

There is [G. Jay Kerns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1108/g-jay-kerns)'

[Introduction to Probability and Statistics Using R](http://ipsur.org/)

which is [freely](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) available.

Perhaps it is slightly more theoretical than an R primer.

The [UCLA: Statistical Consulting Group](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/) have great tutorials and examples for using R

Answer (score 1):

Two online user guide for R:

[statmethods.net](http://statmethods.net)

[wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/)

Very helpful for me!